# Groovy AST method call expression's Target Method not set

Tags: groovy

I am parsing my groovy script's AST, I have a customization that hooks into the SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS_PHASE. I also have CompileStatic turned on

1. I want to understand what the target method for a method call expression is
2. This seems be set when the compile static kicks in but that is only in instruction_Selection phase. I need it in my customizer which triggers in the SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS phase
3. How do I move this up to the semantic analysis phase or conversely is it possible to make code insertions in the INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me

1. Do code insertions after static compile in the INSTRUCTION_SELECTION phase
2. To ensure that my code insertions are statically compiled, I set methodTarget myself in all the code that I insert
3. The compile process then links all inserted code statically to their respective calls